# display fields from table and display as a textfield,with condition

Tags: validation, inputfield

I have fetch the data using query from apex.from two obeject with look up relation
query is

```
setCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT ProgramName__c, 
       ProgramGenre__c,(SELECT NumberofBroadcasts__c FROM Commercial_Slots__r) 
        FROM Timeslot__c]));
```

now when i m going to display the given fields on vf page i have to check that NumberofBroadcasts__c field present or not. if present display the value in inputfield else i have to display 0,
but i am unable to do that, so please help me.

```
<apex:repeat value="{!o.Commercial_Slots__r}" var="c">
  <apex:column > 
    <apex:facet name="header">Number of broadcast </apex:facet> 
    <apex:inputField value="{! IF((c.NumberofBroadcasts__c == 'null'), '0', c.NumberofBroadcasts__c)}"/> 
  </apex:column> 
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: it would be great if you can update this question with details. i.e. your complete apex class and vf page so that we can know what variables you are using on your page and what is missing and I am assuming htat when you say field present or not you mean it's value not it added to SOQL correct ?

Comment: <apex:repeat value="{!o.Commercial_Slots__r}" var="c">
                
               <apex:column >
     <apex:facet name="header">Number of broadcast </apex:facet>
     <apex:inputField value="{! IF((c.NumberofBroadcasts__c == 'null'), '0', c.NumberofBroadcasts__c)}"/>
     </apex:column>
                
                </apex:repeat>   setCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT ProgramName__c, 
       ProgramGenre__c,(SELECT NumberofBroadcasts__c FROM Commercial_Slots__r) 
        FROM Timeslot__c])); when try to display the field value in inputtextfield

Comment: so it display error on input text fields

Answer (score 0):

update your code to

```
<apex:repeat value="{!o.Commercial_Slots__r}" var="c">
  <apex:column > 
    <apex:facet name="header">Number of broadcast </apex:facet> 
    <apex:inputField value="{!c.NumberofBroadcasts__c} " rendered="{!c.NumberofBroadcasts__c != null}"/>
      <apex:inputText rendered="{!c.NumberofBroadcasts__c == null}" value="0"/>
  </apex:column> 
</apex:repeat>
```

You need to put if conditions in rendered part

Comment: okk..sir but i want that 0 value in text field so how to write that condition with inputfield value 0 in that

Comment: inputfield only works with Object field you cannot give 0 in that. To print 0 you need to use 'apex:inputtext'.

Comment: <apex:repeat value="{!o.Commercial_Slots__r}" var="c">
     <apex:column > 
      <apex:facet name="header">Number of broadcast </apex:facet> 
      <apex:inputField value="{!c.NumberofBroadcasts__c} " rendered="{!c.NumberofBroadcasts__c != null}"/>
        <apex:inputField rendered="{!c.NumberofBroadcasts__c == null}"></apex:inputField>
     </apex:column> 
   </apex:repeat> i try this ..it show no error but on output side it display nothing

Comment: <apex:repeat value="{!o.Commercial_Slots__r}" var="c">
     <apex:column > 
      <apex:facet name="header">Number of broadcast </apex:facet> 
      <apex:inputField value="{!c.NumberofBroadcasts__c} " rendered="{!c.NumberofBroadcasts__c != null}"/>
        <apex:inputText rendered="{!c.NumberofBroadcasts__c == null}">0</apex:inputText>
     </apex:column> 
   </apex:repeat> this is not also working...

Comment: @NiranjanChakankar  Put 0 in value see my updated answer.

Comment: sorry sir...but showing error on inputtext field

Comment: what error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this solution.

List obj = new List;
for(obj ob :[select .....]) {
if(ob.NumberofBroadcasts__c == null) {ob.NumberofBroadcasts__c = 0;}
obj.add(ob);
}